# Html Validation Column 19: An body start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open

Tags: html, validation, w3c-validation

I have just made a simple page but i am unable to figure out what wrong please let me know what to edit whenever i validate it via W3 it give error

[Link to HTML validation][1]

Error Line 12, Column 19: An body start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open.

regards

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear enough: you have two `<body>` tags.

From your page source code:

```
<body>
<body class="menu">
<a href="mailto:mail@example.com" class="email">Contact</a>
<a href="resume">Resume</a>
</div>
```

I imagine the second `<body>` should actually be a `<div>`.

Comment: i have edited it to div and it gives more errors then .... do you want me to post source code ? :)

Comment: No. Just read the error messages carefully and fix the problems. The messages are usually clear enough. For someone who professes an interest in hacking I'd expect you to cope with this easily.